# Does adhoc builds have DEBUG defined?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

Do adhoc builds have DEBUG defined?
In development it is defined, but I don't know in adhoc. I guess is not defined in release.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try doing: 
#ifdef DEBUG 
                NSLog(@"Debug On"); 
#endif 
and see what happens in different circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how what your building.
You can sign a Debug build with your Adhoc certificate if you want, or you can use the Release to not have Debug defined.

Under Build Settings, you can change the certificate used, and if you edit schemes you can change between Debug and Release.

Comment: Thanks.
Do you know what is the default meaning? I mean, what happens if I do absolutely nothing. Thanks.

Comment: I think when you start it is already on Debug.
In Xcode 4.2, in the top left click on you App name, select edit scheme, and you can select debug and release from there.